# Angular 2 redirect if user have shop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, angular

How i can  make redirect if User -id(this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id) have shop (owner_id) .
Shop.component.ts

```
    owner_id :number;    
private sub: any;
ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.httpService.getShops().subscribe(params => {
       this.owner_id = this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id ;
    console.log(this.sub)
        console.log(this.owner_id)
    });
    if (this.sub) {
      this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    }
```

Http.service.ts

```
    getShops(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/shops.json')
}
```

I use Rails 5 for api and auth token. Thanks for help. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't complete grasp your intentions here, but this code seems to be what you're after. Hope this helps

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getUserShops(this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id)
    .subscribe((ownerShops) => {
      if (ownerShops.length > 0) {
        // User has at least 1 shop
        this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
      } else {
        // User has no shops
      }
    })
}

getUserShops(ownerId: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpService
    .getShops()
    // Map the returned array to a filtered subset including only the owners id
    .map((shops: any[]) => shops.filter(shop => shop.owner_id === ownerId));
}
```

// http.service.ts

```
export class HttpService {
  getShops(): Observable<Shop[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/shops.json')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
}

export interface Shop {
  owner_id: number | null;
}
```

EDIT: Added update to show example http.service.ts typings

Comment: Thanks . But i have error  - Property 'filter' does not exist on typ
e 'Response'. i using import 'rxjs/operator/filter'; and import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

Comment: That's a typescript issue due to you having not set a proper type on the httpService.getShops()

as a temporary fix, you can assign `.map((shops: any[]) => ...` to override the Response type given. Though id recommend adding a typing to your getShops() to correctly match your expected response :)

EDIT: I've gone ahead and added an example to my answer with minimal typings for http.service.ts - this should help you more

Comment: I have added code to my answer already in the edit. The changes would need to be made in your http.service.ts as you're currently only sending the `Response` instead of the JSON data. 

The changes I wrote will parse the json for you

Comment: What is the error? 
I'm guessing you assigned it inside the class for the service. It must be outside of that block scope as shown in my latest edit

Comment: Thanks a lot of . Worked

Answer (score 1):

```
private sub: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.httpService.getShops()
  .subscribe(params => {
    // code here is executed when the response arrives from the server
    this.owner_id = this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id ;
    console.log(this.sub)
    console.log(this.owner_id)
    if (this.sub) {
      this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    }
  });
  // code here is executed immediately after the request is sent 
  // to the server, but before the response arrives.
}
```

If the code depends on `sub` that you get from `subscribe`, then you need to move the code inside the `subscribe` callback, otherwise it will be executed before `this.sub` gets a value.

Comment: Redirect . But and if users not have shop .

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't have a shop? You only know that when you get the response from the server, do you? So what is the response if there is no shop?

Comment: if user dont have show this user stay in this page . But if user have shop redirect to another page

Comment: How do you determine if it has a shop? Is this if `this.sub` is `false`, or by something else?

Comment: My problem is this . I dont know

Comment: If you don't know, how should I know?

Comment: Yes . My mind is if this.sub false dont redirect , and if true redirect to profile page

Comment: Then I suggest to try the code I posted and report back if it does what you want or not.

Comment: Not code not working . This code redirect always to profile page .

Comment: Where should `this.sub` get its value from? Does `console.log(this.sub)` print the expected value to the console?

Comment: console.log(this.sub) -  undefined . And redirect always not working

Comment: What is `params`? Does it contain the value you want? I have no way of knowing what `sub` is and where you expect it to get a value.

Comment: Params is this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id

Comment: So what is `sub`? Where does it get or where should it get its value from?

Comment: `this.sub = this.httpService.getShops().subscribe(params => {
       this.owner_id = this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id ;
    console.log(this.sub)
        console.log(this.owner_id)
    });`

Comment: So why do you expect `getShops` to return a valid value for `sub`? In your code it will return a `Subscription` where you can unsubscribe the subscription you made with `subscribe`. If you expect `getShops` to get you a meaningful value for `sub` it has to com from `params`, but you mentioned above that `params` is `this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id` which seems unrelated (just my interpretation of your comment).

Comment: My shop.json file `[{"id":3,"name":"mamed","about":"mamedovvdddd","opening":"454","closing":"545","cover":null,"logo":null,"owner_id":null,"created_at":"2017-04-20T12:29:13.000Z","updated_at":"2017-04-20T12:29:13.000Z"},{"id":4,"name":"test","about":"asf","opening":"2","closing":"3","cover":null,"logo":null,"owner_id":1,"created_at":"2017-04-20T12:34:40.000Z","updated_at":"2017-04-20T12:34:40.000Z"}]`

Comment: What part of that defines if there are shops?

Comment: If owner_id  = this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id

Comment: Not sure what that means. If it depends on whether `this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id` has a value, then change `if(this.sub)` to `if(this.owner_id)`

Comment: But if(this,owner_id) and always redirect. Owner_id in shops.json .

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
 owner_id :number;    
    private sub: any;
    ngOnInit() {
            this.httpService.getShops().subscribe(
                 response => {
                   this.sub = response
                  if (this.sub.length>0) {
                     this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
                     }
                }
        });
```

Comment: @fikos I have Updated answer. If you got response as an array, you can check it by its length. In this case, `this.sub` is an array, then it works.